# Android Emulator: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! + 2 other errors

Tags: android, android-studio, emulator

I recently set up android studio, and i began to develop some apps for TVOS, only to find that the emulator WILL NOT RUN. whenever i start the emulator, these errors appear.

```
12:37 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.

12:37 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

12:37 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

i've done all the basic stuff (updating the emulator, etc.) but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling android studio entirely and then re-installing it. It sounds like a temporary problem. Are you using the stable release of android studio or are you using the beta release. (Note: You must go into the system and find the files android studio left. All android studio files must be deleted to clean it.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer solely because it ended out being what I did to fix the problem (albeit over a year ago.)